# asp.net membership in wcf

Tags: wcf, asp.net-membership

I'm at a loss and cannot seem to get a handle on the issue. Google has only left me more confused.

What I need to do is create a WCF service that is hosted in IIS that will act as my authentication service. I want to use the asp.net membership users/roles/profiles.

The service needs to be consumed by multiple clients (website, win form app, java, iphone)

Does anyone have a good link or example that isn't 4 years old and doesn't require you to link a dll to each project.

Just a single WCF service hosted in IIS that is used by multiple clients.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do already exists here

http://thinktecture.github.com/

This is a WS-Trust style Secure Token Service (STS) that can integrate with the ASP.Net membership provider, and profile provider. It also supports OAuth, WS -Federation and HTTP GET, so should have what you need.

It is solid, extensible, pretty well documented and creatred by a well respected expert in the field -  Dominic Baier.